# List index running out? Python

Tags: python, list, variables, index-error

I am making a decoder, but when I type a code-word, if the code-word is not after the last one I typed in the list, it throws an error

Code:

```py
CodeNum = 0
while RTs < 9:
        CodeWord = str(input("Code-word: "))
        Stop = ["Stop", "Exit", "End", "Terminate"]
        if CodeWord in Stop:
            break
        while CodeNum < 55:
            if CodeWord == CodeWordsUpC[CodeNum]:
                output.append(LettersUpC[CodeNum])
                break
            else:
                CodeNum = CodeNum + 1
        RTs = RTs + 1
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/mu_code/Encoder_Decoder.py", line 97, in <module>
    if CodeWord == CodeWordsUpC[CodeNum]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
LettersUpC = ["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O",
              "P", "A", "S", "D", "F", "G",
              "H", "J", "K", "L", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", "<",
              ">", "_", ": ", "-"]
```

Comment: Okay, so when you *read the error message*, what is your understanding of what it is telling you? What do you think `IndexError` means? Do you know what a `list index` is? Do you know which line of code it's talking about? Do you understand what the list is on that line, and what the index is? Now, what happens if you try to check the values that are being used? How long is the list? What number is being used for the index? Do you expect that to work? Why?

Comment: Where does `CodeWordsUpC` get its value? What indices do you think can be properly used with it? Why? What indices do you think will be used with it, according to your code structure? Why? Where you have `while CodeNum < 55:`, how did you decide to use the number `55`, and not any other number?

Comment: Separately: do you know what a `dict` is, and what its purpose is? Can you think of a way that using one might help you solve this problem?

Comment: Also: think carefully about how the `CodeNum` value is supposed to work. In particular: what value does it have *before* the loop starts? What value should it have? Does the value ever need to be changed in a way *other than* `CodeNum = CodeNum + 1`? What happens when you type in the *next* word?

Comment: without knowing what `CodeWordsUpC` and `CodeNum` initial values are, this can't be answered

Comment: @njzk2 Karl Knetchel already fixed it!

Comment: @ njzk2 the CodeWordsUpC is 30 Code words long! that's why I didn't show it here. but I guess I could add that if it makes you understand it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was forgeting is that I needed to reset 'CodeNum' to 0

```
output = [":", ]
RTs = 0
InOrOut = str(input("Encode or Decode, E/D: "))
if InOrOut == "D":
    while RTs < 9:
        CodeNum = 0
        CodeWord = str(input("Code-word: "))
        Stop = ["Stop", "Exit", "End", "Terminate"]
        if CodeWord in Stop:
            break
        while CodeNum < 55:
            if CodeWord == CodeWordsUpC[CodeNum]:
                output.append(LettersUpC[CodeNum])
                break
            else:
                CodeNum = CodeNum + 1
        RTs = RTs + 1
    print(str(output[1] + output[2] + output[3]
              + output[4] + output[5] + output[6]
              + output[7] + output[8]))
```

Now it works, thanks Karl Knetchel!